# Delay in Enable and disable fancybox close button

Tags: jquery, fancybox, delay

When fancybox fires the popup I want to have the close button disabled and just enable it after x seconds.

Is there any solution?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one is fun.

If you want to hide the close button to prevent the closing at least during 10 seconds, you may also want to disable closing on click either inside or outside fancybox .... so try `setTimeout` inside the `afterShow` callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeClick: false, // prevents closing when clicking INSIDE fancybox 
    helpers: { overlay: { closeClick: false } }, // prevents closing when clicking OUTSIDE fancybox
    afterShow: function() {
        $(".fancybox-close").hide(); // hide close button
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".fancybox-close").fadeIn();
        }, 10000); // show close button after 10 seconds
    }
});​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUbg2/)**

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.1.3+

Answer (score 1):

for all users of fancybox the current latest version  hide/show close icon with `showCloseButton` doesn't work any more. After looking into the fancybox code i figured out closeBtn should be set to false. Use `'closeBtn' : false` to hide CloseIcon. Thanks