# fancybox-3 close button disable/enable delay not working

Tags: button, delay, fancybox-3

I have my fancybox close button diplay:none; when an iframe opens, I want the close button appears in a delay of x time. exactly like this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUbg2/)**. 
Though it is solved in earlier version of fancy box in **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928018/delay-in-enable-and-disable-fancybox-close-button)**, but in fancybox-3 It works for the first time and thereafter the close button doesn't appear until I refresh the page.

I use the following JS Code for delay:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".fancybox-button--close").show();
  }, 5000);  
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can access the toolbar and make it visible, if needed:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({
  afterShow : function(instance, slide) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        instance.$refs.toolbar.show();
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeWqrJ

But, if you want to toggle that small close button, here is an example:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  toolbar   : false,
  smallBtn  : true,
  afterShow : function(instance, slide) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        slide.$slide.find('.fancybox-close-small').show();
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeWqRJ

Basically, you can access any element either from `instance.$refs` (collection of references to interface elements) or from  `slide.$slide` (parent element of the content).